trying to improve prediction of my xgboost model
I am new to machine learning and here is the problem I am facing:
My dataset has 1000 records. The target is binary - 0 and 1.  Dataset has 10 features.
I have a "test dataset" with 350 recs with same features but no target values.
My task is to get predicted values using my model with dataset and compare against actual values.
I am using xgboost through sklearn and using gridsearch to tune following parameters following this article:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-xgboost-with-codes-python/
Parmaters I am tuning are: n_estimators, min_child_weight, max_depth, subsample, colsample_bytree, learning_rate, reg_alpha, gamma as follows: (n_estimator, min_child_weight), (min_child_weight, max_depth), (subsample, colsample_bytree), rest of them individually.
Splitting dataset into train-test with train = 0.7 (changed from 0.6 to 0.75)
During tuning steps I am getting back train accuracy, test accuracy, auc score, and confusion matrix. Train accuracy reaches limit of .91, test to 0.86 and auc to 0.89. I see TN, FP changing but the change in FN and TP is much slower.
n_estimators, min_child_weight and max_depth seem to have most impact on train accuracy, test accuracy, confusion matrix and auc scores.
Finally, with best combination of parameters values I compute predicted target values.
When I compare with actual values the best result I get is I am predicting 77% values correctly.
I tried random forest, logistic regression, lightgbm and got best results with xgboost.
I created additional features from existing features to see any hidden pattern etc., pruned features based on feature importance scores.
I had expected my score to improve past 77% but it hasn't.
Am I missing important parameters and/ or model for my problem? Is it possible to feed my results to the model to improve my score?
param_test1 = {
'n_estimators':[100,200, 300, 500, 1000], 
  
'min_child_weight':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

}

best_hyperparameters_ = {}

best_values_ = {}

gsearch1 = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb.XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.1
                                  ,max_depth=5
                                  , gamma=0
                                  , subsample=0.8 
                                  ,colsample_bytree=0.8
                                  , objective='binary:logistic'
                                  , nthread=4
                                  , scale_pos_weight=1
                                  , seed=v_seed, verbosity=1) 
                                  ,param_grid = param_test1, 
                                  ,scoring='accuracy'
                                  ,n_jobs=1
                                  , cv=5)

gsearch1.fit(x_train, y_train)

best_params = gsearch1.best_params_

best_hyperparameters_ = list(best_params.keys())

best_values_ = list(best_params.values())

v_child_wt = best_values[0]

v_estimators = best_values[1]

xgb_best_model1 =  xgb.XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.1
                 ,n_estimators=v_estimators
                 ,max_depth=3
                 ,min_child_weight=v_child_wt
                 ,gamma=0
                 ,subsample=0.8
                 ,colsample_bytree=0.8
                 ,objective= 'binary:logistic'
                 ,nthread=4
                 ,scale_pos_weight=1
                 ,seed=v_seed
                 ,verbosity=1)

xgb_best_model1.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred_xgb2_tr = xgb_best_model1.predict(x_train)

y_pred_xgb2 = xgb_best_model1.predict(x_test)

accuracy_train = accuracy_score(y_train, y_pred_xgb2_tr)

accuracy_test = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_xgb2) 

print('Best hyperparameters:', best_hyperparameters_)

print('Best values:', best_values_)

print(f'Accuracy (train): {accuracy_train:.6f}')

print(f'Accuracy (test): {accuracy_test:.6f}')

class_report_xgb1 = classification_report(y_test, y_pred_xgb2)

print(f'Classification Report:\n {class_report_xgb1}')

cm_xgb2 = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_xgb2)



ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm_xgb2).plot(colorbar=False)

y_prob2 = xgb_best_model1.predict_proba(x_test)

fpr2, tpr2, thresh2 = roc_curve(y_test, y_prob2[:,1], pos_label=1)

auc_score2 = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_prob2[:,1])

print(f'AUC score(test): {auc_score2:.6f}')

xgb_predictions = xgb_best_model1.predict(feature_test)


Welcome to StackOverflow! Is your quesition specific to the 3.x version of Python, and about Python itself? If not, please use the more general 'python' tag
